# Example for ssh_keys parameter in ansible module vultr_server

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys

I am using ansible 2.9.4 and trying to setup a playbook for provisioning vultr servers.

Using the `vultr_server` module (which works fine) i noticed the `ssh_keys` parameter. The only documentation provided is "List of SSH key names or IDs passed to the server on creation.".

What functionality is provided? Can someone provide an example?

Relevant task:

```
- name: Ensure a cloud server exists
  local_action:
    module: vultr_server
    name: "{{ inventory_hostname_short }}"
    ipv6_enabled: yes
    private_network_enabled: no
    os: "Debian 10 x64 (buster)"
    plan: "4096 MB RAM,128 GB SSD,3.00 TB BW"
    region: Amsterdam
    ssh_keys:
    - id_rsa
    register: result
```

Tasks execution succeeded and a new running instance is available. However, no `authorized_keys` (no `.ssh` directory at all).

Comment: It provides ssh key-based authentication on the provisioned server. basically copies the list of keys to `<user_home>/.ssh/authorized_keys`.  An example can be found here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/vultr_server_module.html

Comment: I expected something like that. Updated my question to make this more clear

Comment: I can't make a test but would expect that. Try creating the .ssh dir manually and see if it actually puts the keys there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the `ssh_keys` must match **the name of the keys known by vultr**. You can create these public named keys via the web console (https://my.vultr.com): Products -> SSH Keys -> Add SSH key.

The specified public keys will be added to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (file will be created automatically).

References

- https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-do-i-generate-ssh-keys/
- https://www.vultr.com/api/#server_create
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/vultr_server_module.html